# One React Handler works, the other does not

Tags: reactjs

I am watching training videos on React by Mosh.

I have an Increment and a Decrement handler, and they are coded alike.

`handleIncrement` works, but `handleDecrement` does not.

There are no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: VS Code screenshot]

[image: Chrome screenshot]

### App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/navbar';
import Counters from './components/counters';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = { 
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
      { id: 5, value: 0 },
    ]
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("App - Constructor");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // make calls to server
    console.log("App - mounted!");
  }

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    console.log('handle Delete: ', counterId);
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(x => x.id !== counterId );
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleDecrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = {...counter};
    counters[index].value--;
    this.setState(counters);
    console.log('decrement counter', counter);
  };

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = {...counter};
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({counters});
    console.log('increment counter', counter);
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    console.log('reset counters');
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({counters});
  };

  render() {
    console.log("App - Rendered");
    return (
      <>
        <NavBar 
          totalCounters={this.state.counters.filter(x => 0 < x.value).length}
        />
        <main role="main" className="container">
          <Counters 
            counters={this.state.counters}
            onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onReset={this.handleReset}
          />
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }

};

export default App;
```

### Counter.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class Counter extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log("prevProps", prevProps);
        console.log("prevState", prevState);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {

    }

    getBadgeClasses = () => {
        let badge = (this.props.counter.value === 0) ? 'bg-warning' : 'bg-primary';
        return 'badge ' + badge + ' m-2';
    }

    formatCount = () => {
        const { value: count } = this.props.counter;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }

    render() { 
        console.log("Counter - Rendered");
        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <div className="col-1">
                    <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <button 
                        onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)} 
                        className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>+</button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => this.props.onDecrement(this.props.counter)}
                        className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2'
                        disabled={this.props.counter.value === 0 ? 'disabled' : ''}>-</button>
                    <button 
                        onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.counter.id)}
                        className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">x</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
 
export default Counter;
```

### Counters.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';

class Counters extends Component {
    render() { 
        console.log("Counters - Rendered");
        const { onReset, counters, onDecrement, onDelete, onIncrement } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button 
                onClick={onReset}
                className="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2">Reset</button>
                {counters.map(counter =>
                    <Counter 
                        key={counter.id} 
                        onDecrement={onDecrement}
                        onDelete={onDelete} 
                        onIncrement={onIncrement}
                        counter={counter}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Counters;
```

Comment: "handleIncrement works, but handleDecrement does not." -- please explain.

Comment: @ScottHunter, when I click the "+" on the form, the value increments. When I click "-" on the form, I get the console messages, but the value doesn't change.

Comment: Offtopic: but if you are just learning react I would avoid any tutorial that uses class component and go for functional components only. Class components is legacy React and they don't have hooks, which are super important in modern React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 48 in App.js where you are setting state, you have wrapped counter with curly braces; on line 39 you have simply passed counter in the setState.

Comment: That was amazing! Thank you! I've been struggling with that for a week.